# Java not sorting properly

Tags: java

How do I create a String with alphabetical order letters taken from another String?

Let's say I have something like this

```
String theWord = "Hello";
```

How do I compute the new String to make it look like"

```
ehllo
```

Which is theWord but sorted character by character in alphabetical order.

I came up with this but I am not sure why it isn't working, it just prints out "Hello"

```
char[] chars = theWord.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
String newWord = new String(chars);
System.out.println(newWord);
```

Comment: Because capital letters come before lowercase letters.

Comment: Why do you blame Java? Java is very well documented and will tell you exactly what it is doing. [The first rule of programming.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Because capital H is before the lower case letters.

```
String theWord = "hello";
```

Outputs, as you expected (with no other changes to your code)

```
ehllo
```

Comment: A quick solution would be to call `char[] chars = theWord.toLowercase().toCharArray();` But that does mean that the sorted word will be all lower case. Note for future reference, chars are ordered according to the ASCII table which you can google easily enough.

Comment: @PerryMonschau What is the last character represented in ASCII?

Comment: Well now that depends if we're allowing Unicode characters as well. You see characters are not just letters but also any textual commands including new line, backspace etc. In the 8-bit model the DEL command is the last character, but z is the last letter. However in Unicode there can be millions of characters, including foreign language characters and mathematical symbols. So it really depends on what your intentions are how much of it matters.

Comment: @PerryMonschau What I was getting at is that character literals represent only UTF-16 code units. So they ordered based on that, not based on ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

**In sorting first the uppercase letters sort and followed by lowercase letters.**
In your example since H is in upper case it comes first suppose you provide the input String as `HEllo` then your output will be `EHllo`. In addition if your provide input string combination of uppercase,lowercase and numbers, then the sort() method sorts the number first followed by uppercase followed by lowercase.
Example if you provide input string as `HEllo397` you will get the output as `379EHllo`

So there is nothing wrong with the code.